Datepicker from Material with wrong first Date
I use Material 16 and when I open the date picker, Monday is always shown with the first day. But the current one is correct but it always starts counting from Monday, how can I change that?
<div class="date-wrapper2">
 <mat-form-field>
 <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
 <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2">
 <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
 <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
 <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
 </mat-form-field>
</div>



